# Ensure Info.plist contains a value for the key CFBundleExecutable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode15

I'm trying to build an iOS xcode project on my own physical iPhone using Xcode 15.2 and I get this issue:

Failure Reason: The path to the provided bundle's main executable could not be determined.
Recovery Suggestion: Ensure that your bundle's Info.plist contains a value for the key CFBundleExecutable.

How can I fix that?

I try deleting Derived Data, reinstalling my device as builder device for Xcode, restart iPhone and Mac

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Executable file` in your plist file by `Project -> Select Target -> Info`. By default, it will take `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}` = `$EXECUTABLE_PREFIX$PRODUCT_NAME$EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX`. Which means:

> Specifies the name of the binary the target produces.

If you don't see it here. Simply add `CFBundleExecutable` key with `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}`.

Notice: Don't put any special characters on your Product Name.